# Error while formatting float and string values

Tags: python

Getting error while formatting float and string

fm1 is the format specified to write in the format: bigram count probability

```
fmt1 = '{{:<{}s}} {{:<{},d}} {{:<{},f}}'.format(20,20,25)

if(words[i]+" "+words[i+1]) in bigrams.keys():
                    #print("1")
                    f.write(fmt1.format(words[i]+" "+words[i+1],bigrams[words[i]+" "+words[i+1]],computeBigramProbilities(bigrams[words[i]+" "+words[i+1]],unigrams[words[i]])+"\n"))
                else:
                    #print("2")
                    f.write(fmt1.format(words[i]+" "+words[i+1],0,0.00+"\n"))
```

While running the program I am getting the below error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Where do you define words? If they are floats then you can't add them to a string as that is not a defined thing. Try just using format to make your keys.

Comment: Yes, because you are trying to add a `float` and a `str` right here: `0.00+"\n"`, Python is strongly typed, and doesn't allow that.

Comment: How do i write this combination to a file: word-count-probability ?